# Accessing an event initialized variable from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm trying to use a variable (`fileName`) that is initialized by a drag&drop event from another class.

Ideally it would be nice if `fileName` were a sort of global variable that would permanently be updated by the drag&drop event. I could then call that already updated variable from another class. Is it possible?

```
public void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileName = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

    if (fileName != null)
    {
        foreach (string name in fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString(name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `fileName` contains the directory/directories from where the file was dragged from. I want to use that directory in a custom data printing function, in a separate class, that requires the path for the file.

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really just need to read the variable from another class. The variable `fileName` contains the directory (or directories) from where the file was dragged from. I wanted to use that directory in a custom data printing function (in a separate class) that requires the path for a file name.

Comment: You could always use this dragdrop event to raise another custom event that your other forms listen for.  The custom event could carry the new filename.

Comment: That sounds very ideal, but I've never done it. Do you have a reference point I can use as an example? I'm not sure I understand how this custom even would need to be created.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without more context. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on what will make a good code example, and how to better present your question.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correctly then the following options might do the job for you:

1. Expose FileNames as a property that would be referenced by the other class.
2. Forward the data you're receiving on the DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop event handle using your own event for example :

   ```
   public class YourClass
   {
        // The other class would register to this event 
        public event Action<string[]> TextBoxDropDown;

        public void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(
           object sender,DragEventArgs e)
        { 
           string[] fileNames = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) 
                                  as string[];
           if (fileNames != null&&TextBoxDropDown !=null)
            {
                TextBoxDropDown(fileNames);    
            }
        }
   }
   ```